# How to send application/json data with image file in python flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am using the send_from_directory function.

```
@app.route('/get_data',methods=["GET"])
def get_data():
    path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], 'uploads')
    return send_from_directory(path,"cat.jpg")
```

Comment: check in the post request `request.files`

Comment: please elaborate? i want to return image file with a dictionary.

Comment: Please give a more detailed explanation - do you want to return an image or json data?

Comment: both at a same time @OferArial

Comment: HTTP responses should respond with one type of data. It depends on what is your client does - for example, you can return a json to the client which contains a URL for an image and than the client should fetch that imgae. Another option is to return an image and return the json data in an HTTP header, or as the first option - have an http header that contains a URL for the JSON data, and make the client fetch the JSON data later.

Comment: I added an answer so the question will be answered properly. if it helps you - please accept it :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP responses should respond with one type of data. It depends on what is your client does.

For example, you can return a json to the client which contains a URL for an image and than the client should fetch that imgae.

Another option is to return an image and return the json data in an HTTP header, or as the first option - have an http header that contains a URL for the JSON data, and make the client fetch the JSON data later.

Good luck :)